# Big Event planning and floor layout

Tags: contact-manager, floor-plan

I'm Looking for any software that can help manage and run convention style or big event functionality.

Floor planning is crucial for vendors and guests. Looking for the most cost effective solutions but any worthy paid applications are welcome for suggestion.

A one program does all solution is ideal, but I'm open to modular solutions as well.

Comment: Wouldn't any regular 2D CAD software work?

Comment: Yes it would, and so does graph paper, but just trying to put the feelers out for any proggies geared for the layout, and I suppose there are some out there suited for many aspects of running a functional event on top of layout design, I should probably implicitly say Im looking for such, but I have to say CAD could help a lot with layout design.

Comment: You could also try perhaps some illustration application like Inkscape, being that it is probably "lighter" and more straightforward, and easier to move objects around in. It may also be faster to get good graphical presentation

Comment: Sounds great.. I'm gaining interest in inkscape for graphics as well, and I'm liking the cost elimination.. looks like a good start, and I'll be installing this when I get to my computer to give it a test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Full disclosure, I work for the company I am about to talk about*

[SpinGo Event Master](https://www.spingo.com/eventmaster) is an event management software that is effective for vendor and floor management as well as being a cost-effective solution.

SpinGo Event Master has the functionality needed to run a convention or show and includes:

- Vendor floor map.
- Onsite check-in and registration.
- Lead retrieval.
- Vendor application approval and denial.
- Vendor & Attendee registration and badging.
- Vendor communication.

The software also includes ticketing, volunteer management, event schedule/agenda, attendee app, celebrity/keynote manager, badge/wristbrand onsite printing.

Answer (score 1):

[Draw.io/app.diagram.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) has floor plans:

[image]